# What does this icon mean in Gmail for attachments?

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

Some files I attach in Gmail have this icon next to it, while others have a different icon that looks like a piece of paper with a bent corner. The format is all the same, what does this icon signify?

[image: icon]

Corruption? I have checked the file and re-added it, and it works fine.

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen that icon before. Kind of looks like a file folder with a line across it. Adding a screenshot showing when / where you see this may add context that helps someone answer your question. I'm speculating, but are some files attached from Drive and some from your local storage?